# How to get all the selected value in a multiple select?

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have this `select`:

```
<select id="ddrp1" multiple onchange="SelectChanged(this)">
    <option value="">Select an option</option>
    <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="Option 5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

I want display all the selected value because this `select` allow to choice multiple elements, so I did this:

```
$("#ddrp1").on("change", function() {
   alert(this.value); 
});
```

But this will only display the first value selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery you could use simply `.val()` method to return all the selected values.

**NOTE:** You must remove the inline-event `onchange`, since you already attaching the `change` event in your JS code.

```js
$("#ddrp1").on("change", function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddrp1" multiple>
  <option value="">Select an option</option>
  <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="Option 5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```